# Website to clearly explain "why open data" to non-governmental stakeholders

Tags: uses-of-open-data, releasing-data

I haven't found a clear website that I could share with non-profit organizations or companies, about how their opening of data can be used by the community for transparency, marketing, good PR, building a community, 3rd party apps, etc.

The challenge is that opening data is done for different reasons by each stakeholder, so there is no one-size-fits-all answer to the question "why open data?".

This resource from OKFN very much focuses on governments: https://okfn.org/opendata/why-open-data/

This question focuses on governments as well: [What are good examples of how open data is driving community development?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1311/1511)

But are there more general examples of websites or documents that could appeal to other potential data-sharers such as companies?

Comment: *"You use our  personal data. Hence, share your trade secrets. Otherwise, we'll expropriate your data centers."* – from a "data socialist" point of view :-). https://t.me/opendatarussiachat/19380

Comment: "Explore mandating access to private sector data.
Policymakers should examine areas where mandating access 
to privately held data could enable innovation, competition 
and growth in priority policy areas. Public bodies should 
explore increasing access to data through procurement 
contracts and when issuing licences to operate services. 
Regulators should support and instigate initiatives that 
standardise access to data, as they have with open banking". From https://www.bennettinstitute.cam.ac.uk/publications/value-data-summary-report/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a useful resource:

https://opendatatoolkit.worldbank.org/en/starting.html

> When government data are made accessible and re-usable, they enable individuals, organizations and even governments themselves to innovate and collaborate in new ways.

With these main points

- Transparency
- Public Service Improvement
- Innovation and Economic Value
- Efficiency

and then lots of links for further reading, policy guidelines, resources, etc...
[image]